# Jsoup changing camelcase tag to lowercase

Tags: jsoup

I am using Jsoup to parse a java-generated xml for some DOM manipulation. However, the in the output xml, all the camel-case xml tags generated by the java programme is getting converted to lowercase. For example the tag

```
`<pageBackgroundcolor></pageBackgroundcolor>`
```

is changing to `<pagebackgroundcolor></pagebackgroundcolor>`

Since the jsoup parsing is being used in an interface programme, changing the tags this way is breaking the code. Please help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parser JSoup change the tags to lower case letter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19666246/parser-jsoup-change-the-tags-to-lower-case-letter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSoup is an HTML parser, and with that said it is not intended for parsing XML documents. The current version of JSoup 1.7.2, will normalize all attributes to lowercase as it is for now.

I would suggest that you use a Java XML parser such as [JDOM](http://www.jdom.org/) instead.

Source:
[JSoup on GitHub - Attribute.java](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/blob/fa9d20a3fb3060daaaa4f183a4be5cf27caf2583/src/main/java/org/jsoup/nodes/Attribute.java)

Comment: Even though jsoup supports an xml parser by now which implicates the intention to parse XML, yet the issue still remains.