# Parser JSoup change the tags to lower case letter

Tags: java, jsoup

I did some research and it seems that is standard Jsoup make this change. I wonder if there is a way to configure this or is there some other Parser I can be converted to a document of Jsoup, or some way to fix this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately not, the constructor of `Tag` class changes the name to lower case:

```
private Tag(String tagName) {
    this.tagName = tagName.toLowerCase();
}
```

But there are two ways to change this behavour:

1. If you want a *clean* solution, you can clone / download the [JSoup Git](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/) and change this line.
2. If you want a *dirty* solution, you can use reflection.

**Example for #2:**

```
Field tagName = Tag.class.getDeclaredField("tagName"); // Get the field which contains the tagname
tagName.setAccessible(true); // Set accessible to allow changes

for( Element element : doc.select("*") ) // Iterate over all tags
{
    Tag tag = element.tag(); // Get the tag of the element
    String value = tagName.get(tag).toString(); // Get the value (= name) of the tag

    if( !value.startsWith("#") ) // You can ignore all tags starting with a '#'
    {
        tagName.set(tag, value.toUpperCase()); // Set the tagname to the uppercase
    }
}

tagName.setAccessible(false); // Revert to false
```

Comment: I had to change much of the code that you mentioned, but using the first alternative, worked very well. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Is #1 really such an effort? I assumed it's only that single line to change.

Comment: becouse i dont use just parser, i use other functions to. if want, i can post de change libray in some one place....

Comment: The names of the classes which you had to change would be great :-) ... only for personal interest.

Comment: Tried solution 1. Not working. Which other classes need to be modified any idea?

Answer (score 6):

Here is a code sample (version >= 1.11.x):

```
Parser parser = Parser.htmlParser();
parser.settings(new ParseSettings(true, true));
Document doc = parser.parseInput(html, baseUrl);
```

Answer (score 4):

There is ParseSettings class introduced in version 1.9.3.
It comes with options to preserve case for tags and attributes.

Answer (score 4):

You must use xmlParser instead of htmlParser and the tags will remain unchanged. One line does the trick:

```
String html = "<camelCaseTag>some text</camelCaseTag>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html, "", Parser.xmlParser());
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using 1.11.1-SNAPSHOT version which does not have this piece of code.

```
private Tag(String tagName) {
    this.tagName = tagName.toLowerCase();
}
```

So I checked `ParseSettings` as suggested above and changed this piece of code from:

```
static {
    htmlDefault = new ParseSettings(false, false);
    preserveCase = new ParseSettings(true, true);
}
```

to:

```
static {
    htmlDefault = new ParseSettings(true, true);
    preserveCase = new ParseSettings(true, true);
}
```

and skipped test cases while building JAR.