# Jsoup converting Capital Tags to Smaller tags afer parse html document

Tags: jsoup

I am using Jsoup for my java programming. In my need to I need to parse capital HTML tags like..

```
<P CLASS="TOC2">
<A NAME="pgfId"></A><SPAN CLASS="cXref_Color">
<A HREF="1.html">Getting Started</A></SPAN>
</P>`enter code here
```

but after parse with jsoup it is converting lower tags.

I am requesting some one please advise how to overcome my issue. I need to main capital tags only. I read somewhere that we need to change Jsoup source code. But no luck. If anyone having modified jsoup jar please share with me.

Comment: Post the link you are trying to parse.

Comment: I am not reading from website. It is my company internal and I could not able to post.

Comment: If you download jsoup and navigate to `Tag.java` you will see in the constructor that it uses `toLowerCase`. If you remove that it might work, but I'm sure that you will break something.

Comment: Make decisions based on lower / upper case is not the best solution. Are there any other things you can build a selector on?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parser JSoup change the tags to lower case letter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19666246/parser-jsoup-change-the-tags-to-lower-case-letter)