# Maintain camel case when using element.tagName(String) in jSoup

Tags: html, jsoup

Im trying to rename an HTML tag in Jsoup as follows -

```
element.tagName("p:panelGroup");
```

However, in the output the case is lowered and I get `p:panelgroup`. Is there a way to maintain the camel case in the output???

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

This is ***not possible yet***. I have posted two **workarounds** [*here*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19666246/parser-jsoup-change-the-tags-to-lower-case-letter/19668326#19668326).

Beside these, you can also *check* [***pull requests***](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/pulls) on [Jsoup's Github](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup) - possible you can find something ready-to-use there.

Comment: I read your solution and I changed private Tag(String tagName) {
    this.tagName = tagName.toLowerCase();
} to private Tag(String tagName) {
    this.tagName = tagName; but still no success.

Comment: Please also change the static method `Tag.valueOf()` since this is used by `tagName()`. Possible the line `tagName = tagName.trim().toLowerCase()` cased the lower case.

Comment: There's a pull request - unfortunately not merged yet - that may help you: https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/pull/480/ But i haven't tested yet.

Comment: Workaround one from the provided link is not working, I think other classes should also be modified, other than Tag class